# 2014 charitable donation (via check); cashed in 2015; can I include on 2015 taxes?

Tags: taxes, donation, amended-tax-return, charitable-contributions

I mailed a check as a donation to a charitable org on 31 Dec 2014.  It was cashed on 9 Jan 2015.  I intended it for 2014 taxes, but forgot to include.  Since it was cashed in 2015, can I include it on my 2015 taxes?  Does it depend on how the charitable org reported it?

Comment: What date does the receipt issued by the charitable organization carry?

Comment: I didn't receive a receipt yet.  We moved shortly after the donation, and didn't receive it--have requested a copy.  Donation was $3K.  I believe the check was mailed on 31 Dec 2014.  I want to do the honest thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write the check and mail it, the donation occurred from your point of view, no matter when it's actually cashed.

For example, from the [NY Community trust's page on the matter](http://www.nycommunitytrust.org/ProfessionalAdvisors/ProfessionalTaxEstatePlanningNotes/TimingofCharitableContributions/tabid/702/Default.aspx):

> A charitable gift by check is effective when the check is delivered or mailed, as long as the check clears in due course, even though a donor theoretically could stop payment at any time until the check is presented for payment.

So, if your check was *mailed* on 12/31/2014 it was in 2014's tax year.  If you *wrote* it on 12/31 but didn't mail it until 1/2/2015, it was in 2015's tax year.

You can still file a 1040X to claim the deduction in 2014, if it's enough that you consider it worth your time to do that.

Comment: On the other hand, who knows *when exactly* you mailed the check? If it cleared on Jan/2, you *could* have dropped it in their box on Jan/1, and who could prove otherwise? (Assuming anyone ever asks). - now if you want to run for president in some years, I'd be careful, because the opposition might dig that out...

Comment: I presume answers here should be legally correct, but yes, odds are this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: As long as it's real, accurate, ,you only claim it once a d moving it from year to year doesn't change the final result...  "The object of the game is to be as honest as the law allows," and I think an auditor would let this slide as less hassle for everyone than filling an amended return for the previous year.

Comment: Joe, I'm nitpicking, but you described exactly the opposite of "cash-based". In cash-based accounting the expense is recognized when paid, while you described an accrual: expense recognized when accrued (check mailed). That said, what you described is exactly how the law deals with donations, which is an exception to the usual cash-basis handling of the deductions on the individual tax return.

Comment: @littleadv I did wonder about that.

Comment: Just speculating, but I'd guess you're safer from an audit point of view to declare it for 2015. Usually if people are going to play games with dates, it's to get a deduction this year rather than next year and not the other way around -- people usually prefer to get money sooner rather than later. Unless the tax implications are radically different, like you were in a much higher tax bracket in 2015. What if some mails a check in mid-January but writes "Dec 31" on it? I'd guess an auditor would look suspiciously on that.

Comment: [IRS reference (assuming US)](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p526/ar02.html#en_US_2015_publink1000229790) *Checks.   A check you mail to a charity is considered delivered on the date you mail it.*

Comment: Since the donation was over $250, you will need a receipt from the charity in order to deduct it (the cancelled check does not suffice).  The charity should have checked the postmark on the envelope and dated their receipt accordingly.